# Cordova getting type error while calling plugin function

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I am new to Cordova,  I am developing a test app for sim info. I am using *cordova-plugin-sim*

I am getting error:

> **Type error: can't call method getSimInfo**

Just in case, I've also used the vibration plugin and it's working fine.

```
window.plugins.sim.getSimInfo(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

Whenever I am using `window.plugins` to call plugin's function I am getting the **`Type Error`**

I am following tutorial from [this link](https://phonegappro.com/get-sim-information-using-phonegap-apache-cordova/)
Plugins that are used without `window.plugins` are working fine.

Please help, Thanks!

The code goes as per follows:

`document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);`
`function onDeviceReady(){`
`try{      cordova.plugins.sim.getSimInfo(successCallback, errorCallback);}`
`catch(ex){alert("error "+ex);}`
`}`
`function successCallback(result) {`
`try{document.getElementById("simInfo").innerHTML=JSON.stringify(result);}`
`catch(ex){alert("error "+ex);}`
`}`
`function errorCallback(error) {`
`document.getElementById("simInfo").innerHTML=JSON.stringify(result);`
`}`

Comment: Can you show more of your code?

Comment: @Shashank Without a sample code we wont be able to pinpoint what exactly is the issue